# Regarding proving a result in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am solving tutorials of an institution which I am not a student as our faculty doesn't gives any.  Please give me some hint in solution of this problem. 
Problem is - let X be a normed linear space.  Prove that X is a Banach space iff $\,\{ x: \|x\| = 1 \}\,$ is complete.

Comment: As a hint, if $x_n$ is Cauchy check that $\|x_n\|$ is Cauchy (hence convergent in $\Bbb R$) and that $x_n/\|x_n\|$ is Cauchy (if $\|x_n\|$ doesn't converge to $0$), hence convergent in the unit sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch of proof.

If $\{x_n\}\subset X$ is Cauchy, and DOES NOT converge to zero, then $\{\|x_n\|\}\subset \mathbb R$ is also Cauchy, and hence convergent, say to $a>0$.

Then, it is not hard to show that $\{\|x_n\|^{-1}x_n\}\subset\{x\in X: \|x\|=1\}$ is also Cauchy, and hence convergent. Say $\|x_n\|^{-1}x_n\to y$.

It is now easy to show that $x_n\to ay$.